# Trying to get rid of a coefficient/factor of an integration upper bound

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

I have an integral similar to the one below and I was wondering if there was an integration rule that would allow to have the "2" factor out of the upper bound and have it in the formula to integrate.

$$\int_{0}^{2t}f(t-\sigma)*\ddot{w}(\sigma)d\sigma$$